# How to retrieve name and icon of WIndows Store App

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I need to retrieve Windows Store App the way like Task Manager does. Is it possible?
I was trying to use Query API and packaging API, reading manifest, but I need to read resources from resources.pri file to get desired info.
Where I can find API which helps me to get Display Name and Icon of Store App?

PS My app is not Windows Store App, written in C++

Comment: Might be helpful https://github.com/luisrigoni/metro-apps-list

Comment: Finally I did it, thanks to @Xyroid. You can use Packaging API to read manifest of Store App (IAppxManifestReader) and use function SHLoadIndirectString if you need to read strings from app resources.

Comment: Function SHLoadIndirectString fails to work inside Windows Store App process. Currently I have not found a workaround for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[List from desktop WPF app all installed WinRT/Metro applications](https://github.com/luisrigoni/metro-apps-list)

[`Windows.Management.Deployment.PackageManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager) class has method to get all packages and then perform XML deseralization of manifest files to get the info. Use `shlwapi.dll` with DLL interop to extract more data using method `SHLoadIndirectString`